# Device waking device when disabled from doing so?

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, sleep, wake-up

I don't want USB devices to wake my PC, and my USB controller is disabled from waking my PC. However, it wakes it anyway. I tried disabling it using  `powercfg /DEVICEDISABLEWAKE`, but it says `You do not have permission to enable or disable device wake.`
[image: Powershell and Device Manager]
How is it still able to wake my computer, and why does the powercfg say access is denied in Admin Powershell?

Comment: Try creating a new user account (with the admin role) and use the same Powershell command on that account (as an Admin). If that works your account has a corrupt profile, in which case you could try ScanDisk and SFC /scannow.